# Every partially ordered set has a maximal well-ordered subset?

Tags: set-theory

Proof that:
Every partially ordered set has a maximal well-ordered subset?

For example, the set $\Bbb Z = \{\ldots, -1, 0, 1, \ldots\}$ has a maximal well-ordered subset?

Comment: It’s not true, For example, $\mathbb Z$ does not have a maximal well-ordered subset using the usual order,

Comment: It is true that every partial order has a maximal totally ordered subset. This can be proved by Zorn’s lemma.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: And is in fact equivalent to Zorn’s lemma.

Answer (score 3):

No, and it is not too tough to show that $\Bbb Z$ has no maximal well-ordered subset.

First, we note that any (nonempty) well-ordered subset of $\Bbb Z$ needs to have a minimum. (Why?)

The above then tells us that given any (nonempty) well-ordered subset of $\Bbb Z$, we can create a strictly larger one by adding any element strictly less than the minimum.

Thus, there can be no maximally well-ordered subset of $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

Aryaman answered the question as written: $\Bbb Z$ does not contain any maximal well-ordered subset. But any well-ordered subset of $\Bbb Z$ is finite or isomorphic to $\Bbb N$, so there is at least a maximal order *type*.

We can do worse if we consider $\Bbb Q$. The rationals, as a linear order, form a universal countable linear order, which means that *every* countable linear order embeds into the rationals. In particular, every countable ordinals embeds.

So not only there is no maximal well-order type of a subset of $\Bbb Q$, the supremum of those order types is itself uncountable.